# Ubuntu command line to switch input from HDMI to DP source on Dell U3415W display monitor

Tags: display

I have two PCs connected to Dell U3415W monitor, one with ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS with HDMI input and other with windows 10 with DP input. What I want to do is toggle between these two input sources without using on screen menu buttons (OSD). For windows, there is dell display manager which does the switching from DP to HDMI input from command line. But I couldn't find any way or monitor tool for switching from HDMI to DP input on ubuntu using command line.

I have tried installing  dell display manager and monitor driver (exe files) using wine on ubuntu but didn't work out. **Has anyone tried changing monitor input source using command line on Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out **ddccontrol** does the job for you on ubuntu. Rest of the details can be read from here https://askubuntu.com/questions/860761/ubuntu-command-line-to-change-input-source-on-a-display-monitor